# code to add data from a form to a table in access

Tags: ms-access

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO convenati(conid, location, surname, firstname, middlename, phone, email, dob, sex, mstatus, status, violated, date)"&_
    "VALUES(" & Me.txtid & ", '" & me txtlocation & "','" & Me.txtsurname & "','" & Me.txtmiddlename & "','" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtphone & "','" & Me.txtemail & "','" & Me. txtdate &"','" &_ Me.cbogender &"','" &_ Me.cbomstatus &"','" &_ Me.cboviolated & "','" & Me.txtdate & "')"
```

Please I need help with this code.

I have a table called `convenati`,  a form called `formconvenati` and a subform called `convenati subform`.

In my table I have these fields:

- conid
- location
- surname
- firstname
- middlename
- phone
- email
- dob
- sex
- mstatus
- status
- violated
- data.

help me with it

Comment: What part do you need help with - you really haven't said much except "here some code, fix it"?  I kind of get this image of Homer Simpson running into a room shouting a load of gibberish and wondering why noone knows what he's on about.  Maybe have a read of these links:  [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: my question is i need help with liking my access from to to a table i have a table called "convernati" within the table i have some field called "conid, location, surname, firstname, middlename, phone, email, dob, sex, mstatus, status, mstatus, violated and date. with a form called "formconvernati" and a sub form called " convenati subform" i need help with the code to do this. hope it is understandable now?

Comment: Hopefully the answer given by @ashleedawg will help, but as (s)he said - it's attention to detail that will fail you in _liking_ your _from_ to a table.

Answer (score 0):

### Some of your problems:

- you're missing a space after the `)`.
- If any of the fields in the table are field type **`Date/Time`**, then there SQL should have `#` around the date, instead of `'`
- Double-check the number of fields you list in the first half of the query, with the data you're adding (in the last half of the query).  One is **missing** somewhere.
- Missing a `.` after a `me.`.
- Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement) at the top of your modules (first line) to help find & fix undeclared/mishandled variables, objects, etc.
- assume you don't have it all squished together like it appears in your example, but if you do, remove all `_`'s except at the end of the line.

  ```
  CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO convenati(conid, location, surname, firstname, " & _
    "middlename, phone, email, dob, sex, mstatus, status, violated, date) " & _
    "VALUES(" & Me.txtid & ", '" & Me.txtlocation & "','" & Me.txtsurname & _
    "','" & Me.txtmiddlename & "','" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtphone & _
    "','" & Me.txtemail & "','" & Me.txtdate & "','" & Me.cbogender & "','" & _
    Me.cbomstatus & "','" & Me.cboviolated & "','" & Me.txtdate & ") "
  ```

Also, is the last field you listed in your question `date` or `data`?

...the problem all these things have in common is **lack of attention to detail**.  "Close" doesn't count in coding.

One way to troubleshoot problems with SQL being used in VBA is to test the actual SQL output of your statement, in an actual query.

Using the statement above as an example, change `CurrentDb.Execute` to `Debug.Print`, and make the next line say `Stop`.  Run your code, and when it breaks at the `Stop`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate Window, and take a look at the complete SQL.

---

If you still can't find a problem, copy and paste that output into a Blank Query (in SQL view) and try running the query.  It it won't run there either, then you need to start removing parts to simplify the query, troubleshooting by the process of elimination.

I don't know what values each of your form controls hold, nor what data type is expected for each of the fields in the table, so I replaced them all with `___` and got:

```
INSERT INTO convenati (conid, location, surname, firstname, middlename, 
    phone, email, dob, sex, mstatus, status, violated, date) VALUES(___, 
    '___','___','___','___','___','___','___','___','___','___','___')
```

More [debugging tips here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).